# Delete all variables (classes) generated by class method python

Tags: python, cython

For some reason, I need to be able to delete all the children (in some sense) that were originated by some method of the class. Here is an example:

```py
class A():
    def __init__(self):
        self.a_val = 56
        self.children = list()

    def __del__(self):
        del self.children

    def gen_b(self):
        return B(self.a_val)

class B():
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.a_val = val
        self.b_val = 87
```

What I want is somehow to append generated class B from `gen_b` to `A().children` so that:

```py
a_class = A()
b_generated = a_class.gen_b()
del a_class
# b_generated is also deleted
```

Additionally, I need this for cython (I use cdef classes), so maybe there are some solutions with `__dealloc__` or other Cython specific notations. All the solutions will be appreciated.

Comment: As (I think) h4z3's answer implies: your `__del__` method is pointless. The references to `self.children` are automatically dropped when the instance is destroyed, but this doesn't cause anything in `self.children` to be destroyed if something else holds a reference to it.

Comment: terminology correction:  in `a_class = A()` you are creating an *instance* of a class, so `a_class` is *not a class*. `A` is a class.

Comment: Yes, both commentators above are right

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What I want is somehow to append generated class B from gen_b to A().children

Just store the new element before returning it and you can do whatever you want with it - including adding to children

```
    def gen_b(self):
        b = B(self.a_val)
        self.children.append(b)
        return b
```

As for `del`... Please [read what del actually does](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-del-statement). The most important part is:

> Deletion of a name removes the binding of that name

So if you do e.g.

```
>>> a_class = A()
>>> a2 = a_class
>>> del a_class
```

a2 still will work and target the same element (because it holds the same reference that `a_class` did). `del` just deletes the name, not the object itself.

You would need a different approach to delete those elements.

Comment: a **weakref** ought to allow tracking of generated B instances without keeping them alive.  but as to “deletion”, not sure.  maybe nulling out all b.attributes ?